# Increment number from a string

Tags: c#

So one of the projects we have for one of our clients allows them to print checks. One of the fields that goes on the check is check number. Currently we are storing the check numbers(for reporting purposes) in a database as an int type.

The problem is that the client wants to increase the size of the check number to 20 digits. One of the features of the project is to auto assign check numbers to each check when printing multiple checks.

So for example they are printing 3 checks. They enter the starting check number as "100123" and then click an "Assign Check Numbers" button at witch point the first check to be printed gets the "100123" that was entered and each following check is given the same number incremented by one so the second check would get "100124", the third would get "100125" and so on.

The problem is that they want a 20 digit check number which is too big for any numerical data type. My only solution is to change the check number to string/varchar but that would break the "Assign Check Numbers" process for multiple checks since I can't increment the string to get the next number.

Any ideas on how I could implement such a requirement?

Comment: Why do they want a 20-digit check number?  Can such a number fit in the MICR line?

Comment: Have you tried `BigInteger`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: [Decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) supports 28 - 29 significant digits.

Comment: @Amy, that is a great idea. I have no clue why they need a check number that long. I'm actually still waiting on more information but I wanted to get a head start on the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Either use a `BigInteger` or use a `decimal`, as both have more than the required precision.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the range of a `ulong` goes from `0` to `18,446,744,073,709,551,615`, which is 20 digits. I'm assuming there won't be any "negative" check numbers. So long as the first two numbers of the check are less than 17, you can do this:

```
ulong checkNumber = ulong.Parse(textCheckNumber);
checkNumber++;
string newCheckNumber = checkNumber.ToString();
```

If there is a possibility that the first two digits are greater than or equal to 17, then you can do this:

```
ulong checkNumber = ulong.Parse(textCheckNumber.SubString(2));
checkNumber++;
string newCheckNumber = textCheckNumber.SubString(0,2) + checkNumber;
```

Comment: I forgot about ulong(not a type a use much). Still it is exactly 20 which, like you said, can cause an issue with the first 2 digits. Your code to convert to numeric value and increment is currently what we do for int. I don't really know how big the first two digits can be but if the increment carries over to the first two digits then the increment process will run into issue.

Comment: Also, is there a database equivalent of ulong?

Comment: @James - Which database server are you using?

Comment: @James - Store it as a `numeric` with a scale of `0`. That should allow for 38 digits. It won't be unsigned, but that's okay. `numeric(20,0)` should do what you need.

Comment: thanks but I think I will probably change to store as varchar(20). Once the number is generated it doesn't need to have any calculations done with it. The only real reason I needed to treat it as a number at all is when the user is printing more than one check at a time and they want to just enter the first check number of the sequentially numbered stack of check paper. The check numbers are actually already printed on the checks. This process is just to associate the number on the printed check to the stored transaction records that are later used for reporting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `long`. Its max value is `2(^64)-1`.

Comment: Long is divided in half. Half for negative and half for positive.

Comment: You may want to use unsigned long to get all values as positive numbers

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the feedback everyone.

Saving to the database as varchar should be fine. Here is what I came up with for the increment based on everyone's feedback.

```
string sampleNum = "01999999999999999997";

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    int first = int.Parse(sampleNum.Substring(0, 2));
    ulong rest = ulong.Parse(sampleNum.Substring(2));

    rest++;
    if (rest > 999999999999999999)
    {
        first++;
        rest = 0;
    }

    sampleNum = first.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + rest.ToString().PadLeft(18, '0');

    Console.WriteLine(sampleNum);
}
```

Here is what I got in the test:

```
01999999999999999998 
01999999999999999999 
02000000000000000000 
02000000000000000001 
02000000000000000002
```